# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a monotonic function, then $f$ is Borel-measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a monotonic function, then $f$ is Borel-measurable.

I know this one has been asked many times before and is also given as example in a lot of measure theory book but I'm still struggling to understand this one.

As $f$ is a monotonic function, $f$ can be an increasing or decreasing function. Without loss of generality, let's suppose $f$ is increasing, that is for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such $x \leq y$, then $f(x) \leq f(y)$.

Ony the other side, proving $f$ as given is a measurable function means that for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ $$\lbrace x \in X \mid f(x) > \alpha\rbrace$$
belongs to $X$. The last set by definition is the same that $f^{-1}((\alpha, +\infty))$. Then every book and previous questions says that this inmediately means that $$\lbrace x \in X \mid f(x) > \alpha\rbrace$$ is $[\alpha, \infty),(\alpha, \infty),\mathbb{R}$ or $\emptyset$. But to be honest, I don't see how these four options really come from, which cases should I consider to conclude this? I would appreciate a detailed explanation of at least 1 or 2 cases, hope to end the proof in the case $f$ is decreasing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the correction: the possibilities are: $\emptyset$, $\mathbb R$, $(a, +\infty)$ and $[a, +\infty)$ for *some* $a$ (not necessarily $a=\alpha$). This may have been a source of confusion for you.

Now for the proof: there are only three possibilities:

- Either $f(x)\le\alpha$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$,
- Or $f(x)>\alpha$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$,
- Or for some $x_1$ we have $f(x_1)\le\alpha$ and for some $x_2$ we have $f(x_2)>\alpha$.

The first possibility gives you $\emptyset$, the second gives you $\mathbb R$. For the third possibility: define $A=\{x|f(x)>\alpha\}$ and $a=inf A$. (The set $A$ is nonempty, as it contains $x_2$, and is bound from below as one such bound is $x_1$, so the infimum exists.)

Now:

- If $x<a$ then $f(x)\le\alpha$ (otherwise $x\in A$ and $x<a$ so $a$ wouldn't be a lower bound).
- If $x>a$ then $f(x)>\alpha$ (otherwise $x$ would be a bigger lower bound so $a$ wouldn't be an infimum of $A$).
- The only question is whether $f(a)\le\alpha$ or $f(a)>\alpha$. If the former, this gives you the answer $(a, +\infty)$, if the latter, this gives you the answer $[a, +\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks!! I really liked your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think we can get this cheaper. If $I=\{f>a\}$ is empty, we are done. If not, then the result follows because $I$ is an interval: for, if not, then there are $x,y\in I$ and a $z\in \mathbb R\setminus I$ such that $x<z<y.$ Since $f$ is increasing, $f(x)\le f(z)\le f(y)$, which puts $z$ in $I$, and this is a contradiction.

Comment: It cannot contain one point.

Comment: @copper.hat right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have different intervals to deal with, and should use different letters for their extremes. The set $\left\{x\in X:f(x)>\alpha\right\}$ will be either empty, $\mathbb{R}$, or of one of the forms $(a,\infty)$ or $[a,\infty)$ for some number $a$ (not $\alpha$).

If the set $\left\{x\in X:f(x)>a\right\}$ is empty, we are done. Otherwise, let  $a=\inf\left\{x\in X:f(x)>\alpha\right\}$. Then there are three possibilities:

1. $a=-\infty$. In this case, there is a sequence $x_n\to-\infty$ such that $f(x_n)>a$. Since $f$ is non-decreasing, then $[x_n,\infty)\subseteq\left\{x\in X:f(x)>\alpha\right\}$, and therefore
   $$\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_n[x_n,\infty)\subseteq\left\{x\in X: f(x)>a\right\}$$

If $a>-\infty$, we have two further cases:

2. If $a\in\left\{x\in X:f(x)>\alpha\right\}$, then I'll leave it to you to prove that $\left\{x\in X:f(x)>\alpha\right\}=[a,\infty)$.
3. In the last case, if $a\not\in\left\{x\in X:f(x)>\alpha\right\}$, I'll leave it to you to prove that $\left\{x\in X:f(x)>\alpha\right\}=(a,\infty)$.

---

For the case of non-increasing functions, you can simply switch $f$ by $-f$, which is non-increasing. Then $-f$ is Borel measurable, so $f=-(-f)$ is Borel measurable as well.

Comment: I fond your reasoning for 1. rather odd. In this case it is clear that $f(x) > \alpha$ for all $x$. Hence, the set in question is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @amsmath It is clear as long as we understand well what an infimum is (as you certainly do). But since this seems to be precisely the problem that the OP has, I though I should add more details, making it clear were the non-decreasing property of $f$ takes place.

Comment: I find it easier to define the infimum as the largest lower bound than by limits.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @LuizCordeiro